# Key repeating when writing map object to XML using OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I am trying to write a map object to an XML file and then read it back. I started with the opencv tutorials but I am facing an issue wherein the key values are repeating. Because of these duplicate key values, I am unable to read the file also.

Sample code:

```
fs << "Mapping";                              // text - mapping
fs << "{";
fs << "One" << 1;
fs << "Two" << 2;
fs << "Three" << 3;
fs << "Four" << 4;
fs << "Five" << 5;
fs << "Six" << 6;
fs << "Seven" << 7;
fs << "Eight" << 8 << "}";
```

XML file:

```
<opencv_storage>
<Mapping>
<One>1</One>
<One>Two</One>
<One>2</One>
<Three>3</Three>
<Three>Four</Three>
<Three>4</Three>
<Five>5</Five>
<Five>Six</Five>
<Five>6</Five>
<Seven>7</Seven>
<Seven>Eight</Seven>
<Seven>8</Seven></Mapping>
</opencv_storage>
```

As can be seen, every third key-value pair is correct. Any idea why this happens? Or any suggestions I can try to find out the problem?

The same happens with YML file also. I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 and Visual studio 2013 Express. I am building on x64 target platform.

Comment: Forgot to mention fs is FileStorage object.